# Cannot run tests without sudo on Mac OS X High Sierra

Tags: macos, npm, jestjs, yarnpkg, lerna

I'm having a very strange issue:

Working on a project, which is a monorepo managed with `lerna`, I am unable to run tests for some reason unless I use sudo. I know it is not a project configuration issue, because no one else on my team is experiencing this problem.

The error, which is thrown immediately, ends up being:

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token
...
/Users/jasmar/dev/project/src/__setup__/setupTest.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import { configure } from 'enzyme';
```

My environment is:

- Mac OS X High Sierra
- yarn (installed via brew)
- Node 8.10.0 (via nvm; installed via curl)

I am an admin on the machine and have run sudo `chmod -R ug+w .` against the project directory to no avail.

I've also tried `npm run test` to no avail.

The test script that yarn runs is `FORCE_COLOR=1 lerna --concurrency=4 run test` and I have tried dropping concurrency to 1.

While running `sudo yarn test` does work, it is problematic as it generates new snapshots with incorrect permissions and makes managing version control extremely difficult.

Any ideas would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

remove the underscores for ***SetUp***

Comment: Any explanation as to why this would help? I seem to remember something about symbols in path names, but I can't recall exactly what it is.

Comment: Very interesting suggestion? I would definitely like to know why you think that might help?

Also, what could cause it to be problematic on my machine, but not the rest of my teams?